# How to substitute the Spring Retryable annotation by specification in a configuration file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, spring-retry

I had success in implementing @Retryable annotation for my code.  However, for compatibility I needed to return to the version of 1.03 for spring-retry.  As I looked at the jar spring-retry-1.0.3.RELEASE.jar there is no annotations, so I need to write something in the configuration file.  My code is very simple:

```
@Service("wsOrderCreationService")
public class WsOrderCreationServiceImpl implements WsOrderCreationService {
...
@Retryable(Exception.class)
private void saveLedger(OrderSkuLedger orderSkuLedger)
{
    orderSkuLedgerService.save(orderSkuLedger);
}
}
```

Comment: did you try <aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="transactional"
        expression="execution(* com..*Service.remoteCall(..))" />
    <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="transactional"
        advice-ref="retryAdvice" order="-1"/>
</aop:config>

<bean id="retryAdvice"
    class="org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor "/>

Comment: I did try - did not work, maybe I specified not correctly. In this case what should I write particularly?

Comment: <aop:config> <aop:pointcut id="retrySave" expression="execution(* your.service.package.WsOrderCreationServiceImpl.saveLedger(..))" /> <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="retrySave" advice-ref="retryAdvice" order="-1"/> </aop:config> <bean id="retryAdvice" class="org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor "/>
did you get any error ?

Comment: The aop xml code is fine, but it appeared that the version of spring-retry available for me is 1.0.3.  This version does not allow XML configuration either